# Mongodb get element of Array

Tags: javascript, mongodb

i try to get one element form array from Mongodb collection. I no need array with all data, i just need one element of it.
So my db is like this:

```
_id: ObjectId("...")
arrayName :Array
    : 'string1'
    : 'string2'
    ...
```

Is there an option to get only one element of an array? for example the first one. 
This is my function, but this return all element of the array.

```
db.collection('collectionName')
  .find()
  .toArray()
  .then((result) => {
    response.data = result;
    res.json(response);
  })
```

I tried to use function findOne() instead of find(), but it does't work the way I want.
thanks for help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieve only the queried element in an object array in MongoDB collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/retrieve-only-the-queried-element-in-an-object-array-in-mongodb-collection)

Comment: Please provide your mongoDB data with proper formate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use it like this

```
db.collection('collectionName').findOne({},function(err,doc){
    //here doc value will return you json so you can push it in array
    let recordarray = []; 
    recordarray.push(doc);
});
```

Comment: ok, but how should I describe the search index? findOne({here?how?},function(err,doc).

Comment: you can define like this findOne({'fieldname':value })